# Two inequalities in $C^*$ algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Under what conditions on a  $C^*$ algebra $A$ we have the following inequality:

$$x^*a^*ax+a^*x^*xa\leq x^*x+a^*x^*ax+x^*a^*xa\;\;\; \forall x,a\in A$$

The  second identity which I am looking for is the following:

Does the following inequality imply that the algebra is commutative:

$$xx^*\leq k x^*x\;\;\forall x\in A$$ for some positive real $k$? What about  if we assume that $k$ is  a fixed positive elemnt of the algebra rather than a positive scalar?

The second question is motivated by the fact that every Banach algebra which satisfies $|ab|\leq k|ba|,\;\;\forall  a,b$ is necessarily a commutative algebra. The proof is based on Liouville theorem. But in our case the conjucation arising from $*$ operation destroy holomorphicity.

Comment: The first inequality is not homogenous in $a$ that is quite strange. By dilation, we may remove the first term on the right.

Comment: Dear Ali, just in case you are in doubt about which answer to accept, I would definitely suggest great Nik Weaver's one

Comment: @PietroMajer  Dear Pietro, Thak you very much for remind me to accept an answer. It is kind of you to remind me and also to suggest another answer to accept not your owns. Both answers are very excellent. Yours and Nik's answer. I wish that I could accept both answer.I am sorry that your heuristic answer would not be the accepted one.    https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1491/why-cant-i-accept-two-answers-to-the-same-question-simultaneously

Comment: To me is a very natural choice, for I learned something from his answer, and nothing from mine ;)

Comment: @PietroMajer I only just now saw your generous comment about my answer.  Getting praise from you is truly an honor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second condition also implies that $A$ is commutative. If $A$ is not commutative then it has an irreducible representation on some Hilbert space $H$ of dimension at least $2$. Find unit vectors $v,w \in H$ with $\langle v, w\rangle = 0$. By Kadison transitivity there exists $x \in A$ with $xv = 0$ and $xw = v$. Then $\langle x^*xv, v\rangle = \|xv\|^2 = 0$ but $\langle xx^*v, v\rangle = \|x^*v\|^2 \neq 0$ because $\langle x^*v, w\rangle = \langle v, xw\rangle = 1$. So $xx^* \leq kx^*x$ is impossible.

(The second part of the question doesn't really make sense because if $k \in A$ then $kx^*x$ will not be positive in general. You could ask about $xx^* \leq x^*kx$, but this would imply $xx^* \leq \|k\|x^*x$ and therefore $A$ must be commutative by the scalar case.)

Answer (score 11):

As observed, the quadratic term may be equivalently removed from the inequality due to different homogeneity; then $x^*a^*ax+a^*x^*xa\leq a^*x^*ax+x^*a^*xa$ can be rewritten $[a,x]^*[a,x]\le0$,  so the condition is exactly: commutativity of $A$.